# I'm confused and helpless about SAF (Storage Access Framework) in Android

Tags: android

I have a problem about mediafiles from the MediaStore to get an outputstream >= Android 5.

My problem is to getting a tree-document uri (for write access) from a MediaStore Uri like "content://media/external/images/media/334",
is there no api for that?

I already set the write permission over Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. But the only way to get write permission to the mediafile is currently only manually make an Tree-Document uri like "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1C10-2004%3A/document/1C10-2004%3Amatze%2FIMG_20160825_191301.jpg"

I have bellyache to construct the tree-uri by my self, is there a way to do this over the Android API?
(I need only a outputstream to the MediaStore file)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is there no api for that?

Off the cuff, that does not look like a `Uri` that you retrieved from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. Only `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` works with `fromTreeUri()` on `DocumentFile`.

> I need only a outputstream to the MediaStore file

In theory, call `openOutputStream()` on `ContentProvider`, with the `Uri`. If this `Uri` is an individual piece of content, then it is not a tree.

Now, I do not know how you got that `Uri`, because you did not explain that in your question. Note that [you only have access to the content identified by a `Uri` for a short time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

> But the only way to get write permission to the mediafile is currently only manually make an Tree-Document uri like

That too does not look a tree. It looks like an individual piece of content, specifically a JPEG.

If the `Uri` does not work directly with `openOutputStream()` immediately after you obtained the `Uri`, then perhaps you should be using other mechanisms for getting the `Uri` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the Uri "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/1C10-2004%3A/document/1C10-2004%3Amatze%2FIMG_20160825_191301.jpg" is a tinkered uri by my self and with this uri i have write permissions to the jpeg. The Outputstream with the ContentProvider works only with internal storage not with SD-Card storage ;-( I need only to access Media files over Outputstream on an external Sd-Card without hacking Uri's. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matze: "is a tinkered uri by my self and with this uri i have write permissions to the jpeg" -- that would appear to represent a security flaw, then. "I need only to access Media files over Outputstream on an external Sd-Card without hacking Uri's" -- have the user choose the media files via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or possibly `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Or, on Android 7.0+, use `StorageManager` and have the user grant you access to the entire removable storage volume.

Comment: I get the image Uri by the camera system event and i would add  special informaton to the image in the background without user interaction by a service. I don't know why Android 5+ has add readonly security to external SD and read/write to internal storage, but i think i wait for next Anroid release that make this thinks easier.

Comment: Thanks for yopur help !